# copying x>a elements from array python

Tags: python, numpy

I currently have an array like `[1,3,3,4,1,6,9,7,3]` and I'm looking for a way of creating a new array of the elements `>=3 and <6` so in this case, the resulting array would be `[3,3,4,3]`. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a double condition `3 <= x < 6` but still numpyic way to do this should be much faster than list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,3,3,4,1,6,9,7,3])
>>> x[(6>x) & (x>=3)]
array([3, 3, 4, 3])
>>> x[(6>x) & (x>=3)].tolist()
[3, 3, 4, 3]
```